# Spring Tool Suite (STS) not downloading Maven Dependencies automatically after starting Spring Starter Project in Mavericks

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite, maven-dependency-plugin

Our Spring Tool Suite (STS) not downloading Maven Dependencies automatically after starting Spring Starter Project with Web Style.

We are using: 
Spring Tool Suite

Version: 3.6.1.RELEASE
Build Id: 201408250818
Platform: Eclipse Luna (4.4)

Maven 3.2.3

This issue is only happening on a computer running Mavericks. Other computers running Mountain Lion seems to run fine.

We have already tried Update the Project, Refreshing, Rebooting, Re-opening STS, opening Preferences >> Maven >> Checking Download repository index updates on startup and Update Maven projects on Startup.

All without success. Anyone having the same issue? Thanks.

Comment: did you tryed to run maven from command line?

Comment: does STS download Maven dependencies for other projects, so this is a problem for Spring Starter projects only? Or is this a general issue for Maven projects inside of STS? I have Mavericks running and it works just fine, so it doesn't seem to be a general issue on Mavericks. Did you try to delete the ~/.m2 repository directory? Sometimes this helps on my machine to get Maven stuff up and running again.

Comment: @Ralph we haven't tried downloading the dependencies from command line. If your question is to wether Maven is working in the command line, then YES, and the version is 3.2.3

Comment: @MartinLippert YES, STS downloads dependencies for other projects. Even for other Spring Starter Projects that aren't "Web" style, it manages to download properly. We have only found this issue specifically for Spring Starter Project with Web Style checked. We haven't tried deleting ˜/.m2 repository directory yet, will try and let you know. Thanks

Comment: @VSH: my question is: is it a eclipse or a maven problem.

Comment: sounds very much like a problem with the Maven repository, so would be good to know if deleting the local Maven repo solves this.